# A silly confusion related to dimension of 2×2 matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the dimension of the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}$$

Dimension of matrix = no of elements in basis

So here we require four elements to express the above matrix

. So the dimension=4.

But if I use the rank-nullity theorem
That is "Rank + nullity = dimension"

Then rank =no of non zero rows in row echelon form =2

And nullity=no of free variables =0

Then dimension =2.
Also I read once that no of columns of any n×n matrix is it's dimension.

I am not getting why I am getting two answers for same question. Please help

Comment: There is no "dimension of a matrix". There is the dimension of the space of 2 by 2 matrices, which is 4. There is also the dimension of the space of linearly independent rows (or columns) of a single matrix, which for your matrix is 2.

Comment: No, the dimension of the (square) matrix is $2$, and usually you will say $2\times2$. It has $4$ coefficients, hence $4$ degrees of freedom, but this is of little importance. It is of rank $2$ because it holds two linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the dimension of the matrix itself (which is $2 \times 2 = 4$ as you can even think of your matrices as bijection of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$) with a dimension of the vectors the matrix operates on by multiplication (which is 2).